# Sitecore Items Services API requests from CD Server

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, content-delivery, sitecore-services-client

The below Url is working fine in our development environment and we want to move the respective config changes to Production CD Server only in order to make those API's public. Will the below API still work in Production CD Server if we move respective configs?

[https:/my_domain/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login](https://%3Cmy_domain%3E/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login)

Also, we are using SXA Sites and there is a requirement for Microsites as well where they are not having any specific site but they are trying to create data items inside a common folder which is out of our SXA Site with domain 'my_domain'. In this case, want to know whether the below Url work after login

[https:/my_domain/sitecore/api/ssc/item/{Item Id out of this site}](https://%3Cmy_domain%3E/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login)

Item will be in different folder outside of the site with domain my_domain.

Comment: Both the api calls are working fine in Production CD instance fortunately.