# Is it possible to access "/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login" API from Content Delivery?

Tags: sitecore-api

We want to have token based authentication for the API set up in Sitecore Content Delivery (CD). Can we access `/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login` API from Content Delivery?

Comment: You should be able to access - see a similar SSE question and comment in this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/16554/4515